# extra parameters in delete action of JQgrid

Tags: javascript, php, jqgrid

I want to pass extra parameters like `action=delete`

```
jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid({
        url: '<?php echo A_CLIENT_URL?>/getClientAppointment/<?= $userdata['U_ID']?>',
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames:['Actions','Service Provider','Service','Created Date','Status','',],  
        height: 250,
        colModel:[
            {name: 'myac', index: '', width: 80, fixed: true, sortable: false, resize: false,
                formatter: 'actions',
                formatoptions: {
                     keys: true,
                     delOptions: {recreateForm: true, beforeShowForm: beforeDeleteCallback},
                     editbutton:false,
                 }
            },
            {name:'USERNAME',index:'USERNAME', width:100,},
            {name:'S_BUSINESSNAME',index:'S_BUSINESSNAME', width:100,},
            {name:'A_CREATED_DATE',index:'A_CREATED_DATE', width:100,},
            {name:'A_STATUS',index:'A_STATUS', width:100,},
            {name:'A_ID',index:'A_ID',hidden:true,key:true},
        ],
```

using this code  I get ope=del and id default but I want more extra parameters, who knows this help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
{name: 'myac', index: '', width: 80, fixed: true, sortable: false, resize: false,
                formatter: 'actions',
                formatoptions: {
                     keys: true,
                     delOptions: {recreateForm: true, beforeShowForm: beforeDeleteCallback,url: 'abc.php?action=delete'},

                     editbutton:false,
                 }
            },
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much I can't believe that it works very fine.

Answer (score 0):

`delOptions` allows you to specify any option or callback of [delGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#delgridrow). So you can use for example

```
delData: { action: "delete" }
```

You should include the value inside of `formatoptions.delOptions` which you use.

Comment: @Nikhil.nj: How exactly looks `formatoptions` in your last test. It should be `formatoptions: {keys: true, delOptions: {recreateForm: true, beforeShowForm: beforeDeleteCallback, delData: { action: "delete" }}, editbutton:false}`. The answer from Dipesh Shihora do **not the same**. It add `action=delete` to the URL instead of including `action=delete` in the body of POST request to `editurl` together with `id` and `oper`. You can use Fiddler, Developer Tools, Firebug or other to trace HTTP request to verify that `action=delete` do added to the data.

Answer (score 0):

One example that works for me:

```
...
$('#jqGrid').navGrid('#jqGridPager',
{ 
    edit: true, 
    add: true, 
    del: true, 
    search: false, 
    refresh: false, 
    view: false, 
    position: "left", 
        cloneToTop: false
    },
    {
        editCaption: "Editar",
        editData: 
        ...
    },
    {
        editCaption: "Delete",
        width: "500",
        delData: {
            your_variable: function() {
                id = $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('getCell', $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'), 'login_id');
                return id;
            },
            another_variable: function() {
               return "something...";
            }
        },
        ...
    }
    ...
```

'login_id' is variable that was defined in colModel.
'your_variable' or 'another_variable' is variables that you will take in your php script, for example. ( $_POST["another_variable"] )

That's it.